# Excel: Find how old is inventory in stock from the date of its purchase with ranges

Tags: excel, range, inventory

I have an issue in which I  have to find how old is the inventory which is stock at a certain date.

I have generated the data for the purchases of inventory and found the days from purchase to balance and the range of days in which the purchase belongs to.

Now I want a formula or macro to help me that for the quantity at the balance date, how many articles are stock for each range of days.

Now suppose that for the item no.429 at balance date which is 31/12/2019, we have a quantity of 9 pcs.
Now from the second table below, it is easily noticed that 2 pcs belong to the range 121-150 days and the remaining 7 range 181-210 days. The logic is that the first articles in, are the first out. So the balance stock will be of the most recent purchases.
The formula needs to be work automatically for all of the ranges below and it stops automatically when the quantity counted is equal of the stock at balance date.

thanks so much for your time and consideration.
Gratefully, 
Gert

How to present the data:

```
Item   Quantity   0-30    31-60  61-90   91-120  121-150  151-150  151-180 181-210  211-240        





Item PurchaseDate  Quantity  Days:Purchase to balance    Range of days
429   23/02/2019     20                 311                  301-330
429   29/03/2019     10                 277                  271-300
429   24/06/2019     20                 190                  181-210
429   06/06/2019     10                 208                  181-210
429   24/08/2019     2                  129                  121-150
```

Comment: It is called "Inventory Age Report" . You can edit the question title.

Answer (score 0):

It is called

**Inventory Age Report**

Say if the stock as on 31/12/2019 is 39 (instead of 9 as you mentioned) then make a column stock prior to purchase and aged stock as shown in image below. Then make a pivot.

Formula in H15 and copied above is `=IF(A15<>A16,G15,IF(H16-C15<0,0,H16-C15))`. Formula in I15 and copied above is `=IF(A15<>A16,0,H16-H15)`

[image]

Suggestion: In age column, if age is less than 100 days mention it as '001-030 ,   '031-060 , '061-090 , and '091-120 so that the pivot columns are sorted accordingly.